# Is there a method in python that's like os.path.split for other delimiters?

Tags: python, string

I want to use something like this:

```
os.path.split("C:\\a\\b\\c")
```

With this kind of output:

('C:\a\b', 'c')

---

However I want it to work on other delimiters like this:

```
method ('a_b_c_d')
```

With this kind of output:

('a_b_c', 'd')

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> 'a_b_c_d'.rsplit('_', 1)
['a_b_c', 'd']
```

> Help on built-in function rsplit:
>
> rsplit(...)
>   `S.rsplit([sep [,maxsplit]])` -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
>   delimiter string, starting at the end of the string and working
>   to the front.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are
>   done. If sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string
>   is a separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.split(separator)
```

Comment: that produces ["a", "b", "c", "d"]